# Has anyone done a python tornado compatible firebase implementation?

Tags: python, firebase

I did a search but did not come up with any hits for a tornado.websocket implementation of the  firebase sdk.  Abe Haskin's python-firebasin runs inside a thread.  I know its possible to port thinking about it not sure it is trivial, particularly if you try to make the rootdataref dynamic.  Was wondering if anyone had been down this path?

Comment: We're not aware of any such implementation yet.

Comment: Thanks.  Anant.  I decided it was just plain quicker to  build what I need on the server side with Node. BTW,  python-firebasin has many real world issues.  Not sure if everyone knows that.  I had many issues when exploring that package.

Comment: Eric, you're correct that python-firebasin is more experimental than production ready, but it's getting better all the time. Feel free to create Github issues or pulls for any specific bugs or problems you've found.